# Python Django: How to prevent form field from clearing?

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am working with Python Django and I have this really simple form, consisting of a button and an input field. The problem is that the input field is for some reason cleared after I submit the form. So How can I prevent it from clearing?

This is my python file:

```
def index(request):
    # print(f"its me {os.getcwd()}")
    txt = request.GET.get("some_txt")
    if (request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        print(f"THIS IS THE TEXT VALUE: {txt}")
    else:
        print("Has not been clicked")
    return render(request, "main/index.html")
```

This is the HTML file:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="some_txt">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="mybtn" name="mybtn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You each time render a new form, so if you want to populate the form with the old data, you pass it to the template:

```
def index(request):
    txt = request.GET.get('some_txt', '')
    if (request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        print(f'THIS IS THE TEXT VALUE: {txt}')
    else:
        print('Has not been clicked')
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'txt': txt})
```

and in the the form, you use that as value:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="some_txt" value="{{ txt }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="mybtn" name="mybtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

or with a clear function:

```
def index(request):
    txt = request.GET.get('some_txt', '')
    if request.GET.get('mybtn') == 'mybtn2':
        txt = ''
    else if request.GET.get('mybtn'):
        print(f'THIS IS THE TEXT VALUE: {txt}')
    else:
        print('Has not been clicked')
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'txt': txt})
```

and at the HTML side we thus work with a second button:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="some_txt" value="{{ txt }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="mybtn" name="mybtn">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" value="mybtn2" name="mybtn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh okay i see, it seems to work as it should. But now how can I clear the field? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Nick: by not passing the value to the template/rendering it in the template.

Comment: Im not sure i understand, is this the part you are referring to `{'txt': txt}`?

Comment: @Nick: yes, or `value="{{ txt }"`.

Comment: Well, I either pass the value to the template or not. As far as I know, I cant choose when this should be applied  `value="{{ txt }"`. If I pass the value it will always apply. So what I want is to pass the value, and let the field have that value untill I press a certain button that resets it all

Comment: @Nick: you can make a `<button type="reset">reset</button>` to reset the form. But you thus will have to rerender the form with all the content if you submit the form and want to prevent "clearing" it when rerendering the template.

Comment: I dont think i get it. What im thinking of doing is to create a reset button and connect it to a simple func that does this `txt = ""`. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Nick: you can implement an extra button with `value="mybtn2"`, check this in the view, and set `txt = ''` in the view if you clicked that button instead.

Comment: Okay I see. Is there a way of resetting the form using an already created feature?

Comment: @Nick: no, the HTML reset will reset it to the *original* value, so here the `{{ txt }}`.

Comment: When I create a new button and listen for any clicks and then do `txt = ''` but when i try to connect it to an function that i call when the new button is clicked the field isnt cleared. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick: see edit.

Comment: Thats what i have done, and it works. But when I replace `txt = ''` with `some_func(request)` it doesnt work. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @Nick: you can not just define `some_func`: in that case you need to rewrite the urls to "route" the request to that different view, but here that would make it quite complicate to route one button to another view than the other: typically a form is always submitted to the *same* view that then handles the different cases.